# Unity connect PC host from android client on the same network

Tags: android, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am trying to develop a simple application that requires network connection. I built a simple scene in Unity using Unity's network manager. Right now I can connect to my Android hosted game via my PC game using internal IP address of my android device. However the opposite is not working. If i host game on PC version and try to connect from my android device using internal IP like 192.168.1.xxx it does not work. What am I missing? this seems to be  a trivial problem but couldn't find an answer from googling. Any advice? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem of firewall, check your antivirus and firewall on your PC first.